# Mysql View : Command out of sync

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having a mysql view which is causing error: 
Command out of sync. cant execute this command now.
View is created or altered. but when goes to view View Details.. this error is thrown. Kindly help as soon as possible.

```
    CREATE VIEW vw_member_information_details
    AS
    SELECT mi.*,DATE_FORMAT(minfoDOB,'%M %d, %Y')AS dateofBirth,
    (DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%Y')-DATE_FORMAT(minfoDOB,'%Y'))AS Age,
    CASE WHEN mi.minfoProfileCreatedFor='950' THEN '' ELSE ch.chName END AS profCreatedBy,
    CASE WHEN mi.minfoHeight=0 THEN 'NA' ELSE ch1.chName END AS height,
    CASE WHEN mi.minfoReligion=0 THEN 'NA' ELSE ch2.chName END AS religion,
    CASE WHEN mi.minfoMotherTounge=0 THEN 'NA' ELSE ch3.chName END AS mothertounge,
    CASE WHEN mi.minfoCommunity=0 THEN 'NA' ELSE ch4.chName END AS community,
    CASE WHEN mi.minfoNakshtra=0 THEN 'NA' ELSE ch5.chName END AS nakshatra,
    CASE WHEN mi.minfoCity=0 THEN 'NA' ELSE ch6.chName END AS city,
    CASE WHEN mi.minfoCountry=0 THEN 'NA' ELSE ch7.chName END AS country,
    CASE WHEN me.eduMaster=0 THEN 'NA' ELSE ch8.chName END AS eduMaster,
    CASE WHEN me.eduIn=0 THEN 'NA' ELSE ch9.chName END AS eduIn,
    CASE WHEN mi.minfoWorkingAs =0 THEN 'NA' ELSE ch10.chName END AS workingAs,
    CASE WHEN mi.minfoRashi=0 THEN 'NA' ELSE ch11.chName END AS rashi,
    CASE WHEN mi.minfoMaritalStatus=0 THEN 'NA' ELSE ch12.chName END AS maritalStatus,
    CASE WHEN mi.minfoManglik=0 THEN 'NA' ELSE ch13.chName END AS manglik,
    CASE WHEN mi.minfoSubCommunity='' THEN 'NA' ELSE mi.minfoSubCommunity END AS subCommunity,
    CASE WHEN mi.minfoBodyWeight=0 THEN 'NA' ELSE mi.minfoBodyWeight END AS weight,
    CASE WHEN mi.minfoBodyWeight=0 THEN 'NA' ELSE ch16.chName END AS weightIn,
    ch15.chName AS gender,
    CASE WHEN mi.minfoHealthInfo=0 THEN 'NA' ELSE ch17.chName END AS healthInfo,
    CASE WHEN mi.minfoSkinTone=0 THEN 'NA' ELSE ch18.chName END AS skinTone,
    CASE WHEN mi.minfoDisability=0 THEN 'NA' ELSE ch19.chName END AS disability,
    CASE WHEN mi.minfoBloodGroup=0 THEN 'NA' ELSE ch20.chName END AS bloodGroup,
    CASE WHEN mi.minfoGotra=0 THEN 'NA' ELSE ch21.chName END AS gotra,
    CASE WHEN mi.minfoFatherStatus=0 THEN 'NA' ELSE ch22.chName END AS fatherStatus,
    CASE WHEN mi.minfoMotherStatus=0 THEN 'NA' ELSE ch23.chName END AS motherStatus,    
    CASE WHEN mi.minfoAffluenceLevel=0 THEN 'NA' ELSE ch24.chName END AS affluenceLevel,
    CASE WHEN mi.minfoFamilyValues=0 THEN 'NA' ELSE ch25.chName END AS familyValues,
    CASE WHEN mi.minfoWorkingWith=0 THEN 'NA' ELSE ch26.chName END AS workingWith,
    CASE WHEN mi.minfoEmployerName='' THEN 'NA' ELSE mi.minfoEmployerName END AS employerName,
    CASE WHEN mi.minfoAnnualIncome=0 THEN 'NA' ELSE ch27.chName END AS annualIncome,    
    CASE WHEN mi.minfoDiet=0 THEN 'NA' ELSE ch28.chName END AS diet,
    CASE WHEN mi.minfoSmoke=0 THEN 'NA' ELSE ch29.chName END AS smoke,
    CASE WHEN mi.minfoDrink=0 THEN 'NA' ELSE ch30.chName END AS drink,

    CASE WHEN mi.minfoState=0 THEN 'NA' ELSE ch31.chName END AS state,
    CASE WHEN mi.minfoPincode=0 THEN 'NA' ELSE mi.minfoPincode END AS pincode,
    CASE WHEN mi.minfoKundali='' THEN 'NA' ELSE mi.minfoKundali END AS kundali,
    u.user_type,u.user_active,  

    CASE WHEN (SELECT memberPhoto FROM tbl_member_photo WHERE member_Id=mi.minfoId AND isProfile=1 ) IS NOT NULL THEN
    (SELECT memberPhoto FROM tbl_member_photo WHERE member_Id=mi.minfoId AND isProfile=1) ELSE '' END AS memberPhoto,

    CASE WHEN cd.cDetailContactPerson ='' THEN mi.minfoFullName ELSE cd.cDetailContactPerson END AS contactPerson,
    ch32.chName AS relationWithMember,cd.cDetailTimeCallFrom,cd.cDetailCallFromType,cd.cDetailTimeCallTo,   
    cd.cDetailCallToType,

    pp.ppAgeFrom,pp.ppAgeTo,pp.ppHeightFrom,pp.ppHeightTo,
    GROUP_CONCAT(ch33.chName SEPARATOR ', ') AS ppMaritalStatus,
    GROUP_CONCAT(ch34.chName SEPARATOR ', ') AS ppReligion,
    GROUP_CONCAT(ch35.chName SEPARATOR ', ') AS ppMotherTounge,
    GROUP_CONCAT(ch36.chName SEPARATOR ', ') AS ppCommunity,
    GROUP_CONCAT(ch37.chName SEPARATOR ', ') AS ppProfileCreatedBy,
    GROUP_CONCAT(ch38.chName SEPARATOR ', ') AS ppStateLivingIn,
    GROUP_CONCAT(ch39.chName SEPARATOR ', ') AS ppCity,
    GROUP_CONCAT(ch40.chName SEPARATOR ', ') AS ppResidencyStatus,
    GROUP_CONCAT(ch41.chName SEPARATOR ', ') AS ppCountryGrewUp,
    GROUP_CONCAT(ch42.chName SEPARATOR ', ') AS ppEducation,
    GROUP_CONCAT(ch43.chName SEPARATOR ', ') AS ppWorkingWith,
    GROUP_CONCAT(ch44.chName SEPARATOR ', ') AS ppProfessionArea,
    GROUP_CONCAT(ch45.chName SEPARATOR ', ') AS ppBodyType,
    GROUP_CONCAT(ch46.chName SEPARATOR ', ') AS ppSkinTone,
    GROUP_CONCAT(ch49.chName SEPARATOR ', ') AS ppDiet,

    ch48.chName AS ppManglik, ch50.chName AS ppSmoke,ch51.chName AS ppDrink,
    ch52.chName AS ppAnnualIncome,ch53.chName AS ppCountryLivingIn,ch54.chName AS ppDisability,
    ch55.chName AS ppHivPositive    

    FROM tbl_member_info mi    
    LEFT JOIN tbl_member_education me ON mi.minfoId=me.member_Id
    LEFT JOIN  tbl_member_contact_details cd ON mi.minfoId=cd.member_Id
    LEFT JOIN  tbl_partner_preferences pp ON mi.minfoId=pp.member_Id
    LEFT JOIN tbl_users u ON mi.minfoId=u.user_id
    LEFT JOIN tbl_choice_master ch ON ch.chId=mi.minfoProfileCreatedFor
    LEFT JOIN tbl_choice_master ch1 ON ch1.chId=mi.minfoHeight
    LEFT JOIN tbl_choice_master ch2 ON ch2.chId=mi.minfoReligion
    LEFT JOIN tbl_choice_master ch3 ON ch3.chId=mi.minfoMotherTounge
    LEFT JOIN tbl_choice_master ch4 ON ch4.chId=mi.minfoCommunity
    LEFT JOIN tbl_choice_master ch5 ON ch5.chId=mi.minfoNakshtra
    LEFT JOIN tbl_choice_master ch6 ON ch6.chId=mi.minfoCity
    LEFT JOIN tbl_choice_master ch7 ON ch7.chId=mi.minfoCountry
    LEFT JOIN tbl_choice_master ch8 ON ch8.chId=me.eduMaster
    LEFT JOIN tbl_choice_master ch9 ON ch9.chId=me.eduIn
    LEFT JOIN tbl_choice_master ch10 ON ch10.chId=mi.minfoWorkingAs                 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_choice_master ch11 ON ch11.chId=mi.minfoRashi
    LEFT JOIN tbl_choice_master ch12 ON ch12.chId=mi.minfoMaritalStatus
    LEFT JOIN tbl_choice_master ch13 ON ch13.chId=mi.minfoManglik
    LEFT JOIN tbl_choice_master ch15 ON ch15.chId=mi.minfoGender
    LEFT JOIN tbl_choice_master ch16 ON ch16.chId=mi.minfoWeightIn
    LEFT JOIN tbl_choice_master ch17 ON ch17.chId=mi.minfoHealthInfo
    LEFT JOIN tbl_choice_master ch18 ON ch18.chId=mi.minfoSkinTone
    LEFT JOIN tbl_choice_master ch19 ON ch19.chId=mi.minfoDisability
    LEFT JOIN tbl_choice_master ch20 ON ch20.chId=mi.minfoBloodGroup
    LEFT JOIN tbl_choice_master ch21 ON ch21.chId=mi.minfoGotra 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_choice_master ch22 ON ch22.chId=mi.minfoFatherStatus
    LEFT JOIN tbl_choice_master ch23 ON ch23.chId=mi.minfoMotherStatus  
    LEFT JOIN tbl_choice_master ch24 ON ch24.chId=mi.minfoAffluenceLevel
    LEFT JOIN tbl_choice_master ch25 ON ch25.chId=mi.minfoFamilyValues  
    LEFT JOIN tbl_choice_master ch26 ON ch26.chId=mi.minfoWorkingWith
    LEFT JOIN tbl_choice_master ch27 ON ch27.chId=mi.minfoAnnualIncome
    LEFT JOIN tbl_choice_master ch28 ON ch28.chId=mi.minfoDiet  
    LEFT JOIN tbl_choice_master ch29 ON ch29.chId=mi.minfoSmoke
    LEFT JOIN tbl_choice_master ch30 ON ch30.chId=mi.minfoDrink
    LEFT JOIN tbl_choice_master ch31 ON ch31.chId=mi.minfoState
    LEFT JOIN tbl_choice_master ch32 ON ch32.chId=cd.cDetailRelationWithMember

    LEFT JOIN tbl_choice_master ch33 ON pp.ppMaritalStatus LIKE CONCAT('%,',ch33.chId,',%')
    LEFT JOIN tbl_choice_master ch34 ON pp.ppReligion LIKE CONCAT('%,',ch34.chId,',%')
    LEFT JOIN tbl_choice_master ch35 ON pp.ppMotherTounge LIKE CONCAT('%,',ch35.chId,',%')
    LEFT JOIN tbl_choice_master ch36 ON pp.ppCommunity LIKE CONCAT('%,',ch36.chId,',%')
    LEFT JOIN tbl_choice_master ch37 ON pp.ppProfileCreatedBy LIKE CONCAT('%,',ch37.chId,',%')
    LEFT JOIN tbl_choice_master ch38 ON pp.ppStateLivingIn LIKE CONCAT('%,',ch38.chId,',%')
    LEFT JOIN tbl_choice_master ch39 ON pp.ppCity LIKE CONCAT('%,',ch39.chId,',%')
    LEFT JOIN tbl_choice_master ch40 ON pp.ppResidencyStatus LIKE CONCAT('%,',ch40.chId,',%')
    LEFT JOIN tbl_choice_master ch41 ON pp.ppCountryGrewUp LIKE CONCAT('%,',ch41.chId,',%')
    LEFT JOIN tbl_choice_master ch42 ON pp.ppEducation LIKE CONCAT('%,',ch42.chId,',%')
    LEFT JOIN tbl_choice_master ch43 ON pp.ppWorkingWith LIKE CONCAT('%,',ch43.chId,',%')

    LEFT JOIN tbl_choice_master ch44 ON pp.ppProfessionArea LIKE CONCAT('%,',ch44.chId,',%')
    LEFT JOIN tbl_choice_master ch45 ON pp.ppBodyType LIKE CONCAT('%,',ch45.chId,',%')
    LEFT JOIN tbl_choice_master ch46 ON pp.ppSkinTone LIKE CONCAT('%,',ch46.chId,',%')
    LEFT JOIN tbl_choice_master ch49 ON pp.ppDiet LIKE CONCAT('%,',ch49.chId,',%')

    LEFT JOIN tbl_choice_master ch48 ON ch48.chId=pp.ppManglik
    LEFT JOIN tbl_choice_master ch50 ON ch50.chId=pp.ppSmoke
    LEFT JOIN tbl_choice_master ch51 ON ch51.chId=pp.ppDrink
    LEFT JOIN tbl_choice_master ch52 ON ch52.chId=pp.ppAnnualIncome
    LEFT JOIN tbl_choice_master ch53 ON ch53.chId=pp.ppCountryLivingIn  
    LEFT JOIN tbl_choice_master ch54 ON ch54.chId=pp.ppDisability   
    LEFT JOIN tbl_choice_master ch55 ON ch55.chId=pp.ppHivPositive

    WHERE u.user_type=501 GROUP BY mi.minfoId
```

Comment: MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: @jarlh : i am new to stack overflow.. dont know the rules. so sorry ;)

Comment: I can't see any problems with the syntax here. [This link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commands-out-of-sync.html) infers the problem lies with the code you use to interact with the DB, rather than the DB code itself.

Comment: @Bridge : ok.. but did not getting anything.